# Parent method overrides child method when called from parent

Tags: javascript

A terrible title I know, but it's a problem that's easier to define with an example.

I have a code structure which involves multiple levels of inheritance, my example displays only two as this is sufficient to demonstrate the behaviour.

```
var parent = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.parent = function() {
        self.test();
    }

    self.test = function() {
        alert('parent');
    }
};


var child = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.child = function() {
        self.test();
        self.parent();
    }

    self.test = function() {
        alert('child')
    }
};

child.prototype = new parent();

var o = new child();
o.child();
```

I would expect calling the child method would display two alerts, both displaying the text 'child', however this is only true for the first alert, the second displays 'parent'

See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vc8t7fbq/1/

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`o.child();` calls for `child()` method on `o`, which is:

```
self.child = function() {
    self.test();
    self.parent();
}
```

`self.test()` runs and calls the method declared right underneath it, inside `child` as well:

```
self.test = function() {
    alert('child')
}
```

So this is the first alert you see.

The second, is when `self.parent()` runs. Since the prototype of `child` is `parent`, invoking `self.parent()` calls to:

```
self.parent = function() {
    self.test(); 
}
```

I assume your confusion is here - **why `self.test()` calls to the parent instead of the child?**

The reason is that you have this line: `var self = this`. This means that the `this` was already put inside `self`, and it is not reevaluated. Meaning, `self` is the parent.

For evidence, if you switch the method's body to:

```
self.parent = function() {
    this.test(); //will alert "child"
}
```

You would see 2 "child" alerts, since `this` evaluates to the child.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense of something I was struggling to get my head around. Putting 'this' inside self was done to give me a permanent reference for instances such as when self.parent() is invoked by an event and 'this' is now a reference to the html form element... Can you see a way round this?

Comment: You can ask inside the function: `if (this.hasOwnProperty("test")) {...}`. If called from child objects then it will return true since the child has this function (other derived functions might not). Events will probably return false unless you have a global variable/function with that name. Does that help?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was particularly clear with my question, here is an updated version of the fiddle which shows the new issue: http://jsfiddle.net/cu7uphcw/4/ So I am trying to call the child's method from an event which calls a function on the parent

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, here take a look at the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cu7uphcw/5/ I coded what I wrote in the comment. Let me know if it's not clear

Comment: Hi Omri, I see what you mean now and that would work perfectly for the solution given. I have since found an alternative solution making use of jQuery where I can pass the current context in the event data of the event binding which is more effective for my less abstracted problem. Thank you very much for all your help :)